# Error "0 was unexpected at this time." in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, temporary-files

I have a batch file for deleting files older than 5 minutes in a specific subfolder dedicated to temporary files.

The batch is no longer working so I tried running it from within the command prompt and got the "unexpected at this time" error.

Here is the batch file:

```
cd "c:\inetpub\website name\tempfolder"
@ECHO OFF
:: ------------
:: This is where you set the number
:: of minutes you want subtracted
:: from the current date/time.
:: ------------
SET MyMins=5

:: ------------
:: Get current date/time
:: ------------
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-4 DELIMS=/ " %%F IN ('DATE /T') DO (
 SET YYYY=%%H
 SET MM=%%F
 SET DD=%%G
)
FOR /F "TOKENS=5-6 DELIMS=: " %%F IN ('ECHO.^|TIME') DO (
 SET HR=%%F
 SET MN=%%G
)

IF %DD% LSS 10 (SET DD=%DD:~1%)
IF %MM% LSS 10 (SET MM=%MM:~1%)
IF %HR% LSS 10 (SET HR=%HR:~1%)
IF %MN% LSS 10 (SET MN=%MN:~1%)

: ------------
:: Subtract minutes from current time.
:: ------------
SET /A MN=%MN% - %MyMins%

:: ------------
:: Do the massively painful
:: reverse calculations.. :(
:: ------------
:LoopMins
IF /I %MN% GEQ 0 (GOTO LoopHrs)
SET /A MN=%MN% + 60
SET /A HR=%HR% - 1
GOTO LoopMins
:LoopHrs
IF /I %HR% GTR 0 (GOTO LoopDate)
SET /A HR=%HR% + 23
SET /A DD=%DD% - 1
GOTO LoopHrs
:LoopDate
IF /I %DD% GTR 0 (GOTO DONE)
set /A mm=%mm% - 1
if /I %mm% GTR 0 goto ADJUSTDAY
set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1
:ADJUSTDAY
if %mm%==1 goto SET31
if %mm%==2 goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 goto SET31
if %mm%==4 goto SET30
if %mm%==5 goto SET31
if %mm%==6 goto SET30
if %mm%==7 goto SET31
if %mm%==8 goto SET31
if %mm%==9 goto SET30
if %mm%==10 goto SET31
if %mm%==11 goto SET30
if %mm%==12 goto SET31
goto ERROR
:SET31
set /A dd=31 + %dd%
goto LoopDate
:SET30
set /A dd=30 + %dd%
goto LoopDate
:LEAPCHK
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4
if not %tt%==0 goto SET28
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100
if not %tt%==0 goto SET29
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400
if %tt%==0 goto SET29
:SET28
set /A dd=28 + %dd%
goto LoopDate
:SET29
set /A dd=29 + %dd%
goto LoopDate
:DONE
IF %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%
IF %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
IF %HR% LSS 10 SET HR=0%HR%
IF %MN% LSS 10 SET MN=0%MN%


for %%i in (*.*) do (
 set FileName=%%i
 SET FTIME=%%~ti
 CALL :PROCESSFILE
)

set mm=
set yyyy=
set dd=
set thedate=
goto :EOF

:PROCESSFILE
set fyyyy=%FTIME:~6,4%
set fmm=%FTIME:~0,2%
set fdd=%FTIME:~3,2%
SET fhr=%FTIME:~11,2%
SET fmn=%FTIME:~14,2%

if /I %fyyyy% GTR 2069 set fyyyy=19%FTIME:~6,2%

:: --------
:: Deal with File times
:: reported as AM/PM vs.
:: calculated times as 24hr.
:: --------
IF /I "%FTIME:~17,1%" == "P" (
 IF %fhr% LSS 10 (
  SET /A fhr=%fhr:~1,1% + 12
 ) ELSE (
  IF %fhr% LEQ 11 (
   SET /A fhr=%fhr% + 12
  )
 )
)
IF /I "%FTIME:~17,1%" == "A" (
 IF %fhr%==12 (
  SET fhr=00
 )
)

:: +*************************************+
:: | This is where the files are deleted |
:: | Change the ECHO command to DEL to   |
:: | delete. ECHO is used for test.      |
:: +*************************************+
if /I %yyyy%%mm%%dd% GEQ %fyyyy%%fmm%%fdd% (
 IF /I 1%hr%%mn% GEQ 1%fhr%%fmn% (

  DEL %FileName%

 )
)
ECHO Calcdate=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%hr%%mn%

set temp=
set fyyyy=
set fmm=
set fdd=

:EXIT
```

Running it from within the command prompt fails before it even gets past the cd at the beginning. Adding pause commands throughout the code doesn't appear to help diagnose where it's failing.

EDIT: Thanks to user Stephan's suggestion to remove the @echo off so I could see where the code fails. Right here:

```
:LoopMins
IF /I %MN% GEQ 0 (GOTO LoopHrs)
SET /A MN=%MN% + 60
SET /A HR=%HR% - 1
GOTO LoopMins
```

EDIT2: The problem appears to be this segment:

```
IF %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%
IF %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
IF %HR% LSS 10 SET HR=0%HR%
IF %MN% LSS 10 SET MN=0%MN%
```

Because of this, if the batch file is run before 10am, HR will be set to null.

Comment: have you given the file administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes, the file is being run as the administrator

Comment: have you tried commenting the cd command and then copy the file to destination folder and run form command prompt from that location itself?

Comment: I still get the error "0 was unexpected at this time."

Comment: remove the `echo off`.  This should show you, where it fails. (Hint: the failed line is echoed **after** the errormessage) Can you see it? an empty variable in an `if`statement. (Note: also `time` has the `/t`parameter)

Comment: Nice catch Stephan. Looks like it's failing at:

    :LoopMins
IF /I %MN% GEQ 0 (GOTO LoopHrs)
SET /A MN=%MN% + 60
SET /A HR=%HR% - 1
GOTO LoopMins

Comment: yep. Only chance for these lines to fail with "0 was unexpected" is an empty `%MN%`variable (you should see that on your screen). There is a solution for empty variables, but %MN% shouldn't be empty. Look, why it is.

Comment: It's setting the hour correctly, but at the line IF %HR% LSS 10 (SET HR=), %HR% is 9, but it doesn't set it to anything.

Comment: Ok yeah, that's the problem. It apparently will fail if it runs before 10am. Ugh.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear the value in `MN` is *nothing* so the line is resolved to

```
IF /I GEQ 0 (GOTO LoopHrs)
```

`CMD` is expecting `IF [/i] string operator string, where *operator* must be one of the comparison operators or`==`. That's why it's complaining.

In such a slab of code, I'll not bother tracing settings of rogue variables, but there are many, many articles on SO about how to parse date and time from the `%date%` and `%time%` magic variables. You may need to be wary of leading zeroes being replaced by spaces (hint : `set "var=%time: =0%"` may well solve that for you) and then processing leading zeroes (08 and 09 don't play nice; use `set /a var=1%time:m,n%-100` to convert to decimal) is another minefield.

Comment: Must have looked at this a dozen times without realizing what the issue was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, I identified your problem:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=5-6 DELIMS=: " %%F IN ('ECHO.^|TIME') DO (
```

Try on the commandline:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=5-6 DELIMS=: " %F IN ('ECHO.^|TIME') DO echo Hours:%F, Minutes:%G
```

and look at the output.

I suggest using:

```
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=: " %%F IN ('time /t') DO echo Hours:%%F, Minutes:%%G
```

And watch out for the tokens. For my computer settings it is "TOKENS=1,2", but it may vary on other locale settings.

This is my output:

```
C:\>echo.|time
Aktuelle Zeit:  9:12:18,30
Geben Sie die neue Zeit ein:

C:\>time /t
09:12

C:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=3,4 DELIMS=: " %F IN ('ECHO.^|TIME') DO @echo Hours:%F, Minutes:%G
Hours:9, Minutes:12
Hours:die, Minutes:neue

C:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=: " %F IN ('TIME /t') DO @echo Hours:%F, Minutes:%G
Hours:09, Minutes:13

C:\>
```